# Not able to position header properly

Tags: html, css

I want to make a make a header with some menu links. The inner div is not taking the 
margin from top. Please suggest me how to write the css for this.

```
 <div style ="width:100%; background-color:Aqua; height:100px;">

    <div style="width:876px;background-color:Blue;margin:20px auto;height:60px;">
        <h3>menu items</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Also when I resize the browser (pressing shift+ctrl+M on mozilla) the outer dive does not wrap the inner div properly.

Comment: Why not use padding within the header instead of trying to move the inner div by margin?

Answer (score 0):

you are probably getting this because your second width is fixed so no matter the browser size, it is never changing whilst the first width changes since it is in percentage

```
<div style ="width:100%; background-color:Aqua; height:100px;">

    <div style="width:70%;background-color:Blue;margin:20px auto;height:60px;">
        <h3>menu items</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the outer-div to

```
display:inline-block
```

Answer (score 0):

is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh6txmb1/) what you want?

html

```
<div class ='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>
        <h3>menu items</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.outer{
    width:100%; 
    background-color:Aqua;
    height:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
    min-width:876px;
}

.inner {
    width:876px;
    background-color:Blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:60px;
}
```

Comment: I think he is more focus on the responsiveness of the two both inner and outer so he is probably expecting it to be the same ratio/outcome when you resize the browser

Comment: Thanks , It worked.....but on resizing the browser (pressing shift+ctrl+M on mozilla) the outer dive does not wrap the inner div properly.

Comment: @user1410688 sorry not fully understand what you want. Dont have mozilla here.

Comment: If I give the inner div in percentage then is ok but when I give it in pixels then the inner div is not wrapped by the outer div.....